# Core Data Different Object ID For First Time

Tags: ios, core-data

I am using **Entity's Object ID** in order to uniquely identify local notifications and modify them. I observed that first time when I save my entity, it has following `object ID`:

```
<x-coredata:///Task/tE1C5A230-A419-42D5-AF78-3327A09D13BD2>
```

If I don't exit my application, and try to modify notification, `object ID` doesn't change and I can modify my notification.

Now, if I restart my app and try to access that entity again, it has different `object ID`:

```
<x-coredata://D6703834-ECB4-487B-84F8-330A215E16B7/Task/p13>
```

So I can't modify notification, as `object ID` for entity is different. Interesting thing is whenever I access that entity, `Object ID` remains same as the last one.

So my Question here is why Core data shows **different object ID** for the **first time** entity is created? When I try to access entity after opening app again for many times, the object ID (different than the first one) **remains constant**. I am curious to know why is it happening so?

**Please note:**
I know there are many posts on SO pointing out that using Object ID is not a reliable approach. Still I want to know reason that why two IDs are being shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first OID is a temporary OID - a temporary id denotes objects that have not been saved yet. the 2nd id is a permanent one and is assigned to a MO AFTER it has been saved:

so...

```
var objectID = object.objectID
if objectID.temporaryID {
    object.managedObjectContext.save() //try do catch left out
}
objectID = object.objectID
assert(objectID.temporaryID == false)
```

Comment: This was my guess too. I think this will be the reason. Thanks.